# PHP Checking if Array is empty logic not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have a page that loads and creates an empty array:

```
$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] = array();
```

If the user hasn't added any selections that get stored in the array I then check the array and branch accordingly, but there appears to be some error in my `logic/syntax` that is failing here.

Here's where I test if the `$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']` is set but **empty:**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']) && $_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] !== '') {
    // update the selections in a database
} else {
    // nothing selection so just record this in a variable
$selectedItems = 'no selected items were made';
}
```

When testing this with no selections if I print the `$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']` array I get this:

```
[selectedItemIDs] => Array
    (
    )
```

however the `$selectedItems` variable is not being set - it's evaluating the if test as true when I would expect it to be false, but I'm obviously misunderstanding something here.

Comment: You can use count function to check array length

Comment: Well, `array()` is obviously not identical to `''`…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `empty()` function.

> **empty()** - it will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

**Syntax**

```
empty(var_name)
```

**Return value**

```
FALSE if var_name has a non-empty and non-zero value.
```

**Value Type :**

```
Boolean
```

**List of empty things :**

- "0" (0 as a string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "" (an empty string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- "" (an empty string)
- array() (an empty array)
- $var_name; (a variable declared but without a value in a class)

**Code**

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']) ) {
    // update the selections in a database
} else {
    // nothing selection so just record this in a variable
$selectedItems = 'no selected items were made';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] = array();
```

this variable is already set, but is empty. 
`isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'])` check if variable exists, even if it's nothing in.

To check if there is anything just use

```
empty($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']);
```

[PHP DOC - empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'])) {
    // update the selections in a database
} else {
    // nothing selection so just record this in a variable
    $selectedItems = 'no selected items were made';
}
```

`isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'])` => it will check is this parameter is set or not which is correct.

`$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] !== ''` => this will exactly compare that your parameter type is not '' but here i guess your selectedItemIDs is array so it let you go inside

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'])  && $_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] !== ''

Comment: You need to add an explanation to your answer, not in comments.

Comment: isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']) => it will check is this parameter is set or not which is correct.


$_SESSION['selectedItemIDs'] !== '' => this will exectly compare that your parameter type is not '' but here i guess your selectedItemIDs is array so it let you go inside


Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can check the count of this array.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']) && count($_SESSION['selectedItemIDs']) > 0) {
    // update the selections in a database
} else {
    // nothing selection so just record this in a variable
$selectedItems = 'no selected items were made';
}
```

Comment: `empty()` does the same thing.